# Using Array class in parent and child windows (javascript question)

Tags: javascript

I'm actually coding a case where a child popup window transfer data to parent window as:

```
var childArrayData = new Array();
childArrayData[0] = 'Data text1';
childArrayData[1] = 'Data text2';
childArrayData[2] = 'Data text3';
window.opener.parentVariable = childArrayData;
```

I got an error which was solved like:

```
var childArrayData = new window.opener.Array();     <-----
childArrayData[0] = 'Data text1';
childArrayData[1] = 'Data text2';
childArrayData[2] = 'Data text3';
window.opener.parentVariable = childArrayData;
```

Why is Array class different between two different windows? Does it relate to namespacing? May you refer to any article about the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Best,

Esteve

Comment: Are you loading something that could alter the Array object, such as prototype.js?

Comment: ***What*** error? Any time you're asking for help, if you find yourself typing "an error", go back and actually say *what* the error is.

Comment: That's true T.J. I did not write the error because it was not related to the array itself. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Esteve: It was entirely relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. Read [this post on comp.lang.javascript](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/1afbcb0da1cd4aef?pli=1) written by Douglas Crockford.

> When you say `Array`, you are talking
>   about `window.Array`. `window` is the
>   browser's context object, and you get
>   one per page (or frame). All of the
>   arrays created within a context will
>   have their constructor property set to
>   `window.Array`.
>
> An array created in a different
>   context has a different `window.Array`,
>   so your test
>
> ```
> myArray instanceof Array
> ```
>
> fails. The ECMAScript standard does
>   not discuss multiple contexts, even
>   though virtually all implementations
>   support them. The ECMAScript standard
>   also fails to provide a reliable
>   technique for testing the type of
>   arrays. The obvious thing would have
>   been

Answer (score 0):

why are you even using the Array constructor?
try using the [ ] notation instead

which browser are you using btw? are the two frames on the same domain?

Comment: Hi Ken,

in fact, the problem is not only in Array class but in any class "shared" between parent and child windows.

All tests where done on Firefox.

Sorry to ask you, but what do you refer to the domain?

Thanks Ken for your answer ;)

Esteve